# DNS server is being ignored for WiFi devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, opendns

I have a Netgear router / gateway on which I've specified the OpenDNS servers.  The lookup works when I use a computer that connected via ethernet to the router / gateway, but Wifi devices do not use the router DNS.  I've tried several different tactics, and I noticed "DynamicDNS' was enabled by default in the advanced wireless settings (which I've disabled), but still no luck.

I will say that on occasion, the router DNS servers do get picked up by the WiFi devices, but it's intermittent and erratic when that happens.

I really don't know where to go about troubleshooting this, however.

Comment: DynamicDNS is unrelated to your issue - it relates to making your IP address findable, nithing to fo with general DNS lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the WiFi in the exact fashion you did for your *wired* access, and routing. Which is presumably out of a DHCP pool, with a gateway to the internet IP assigned to the (Netgear) router. Do not make the DNS any different than it is for the (working) *wired* traffic (connections). They should both have the same settings.

Comment: That's just it, I can't really configure them separately.  Given that both the wired and wireless devices run through the same router / gateway, doesn't that mean they're going to use the same DHCP server (the router) and whatever DNS server the router is set to use?